# Adding an authentication token to header in Restlet

Tags: java, api, restlet

I am trying to make an API call using Restlet in java however when I run my code I get an **org.restlet.resource.ResourceException: Unauthorized (401) - The request requires user authentication**

The format for the API call is as follows for shell: `curl "<api_url>" \ -H "Authorization: Bearer <api_token_here>"`

However I am unsure how to add this authorization header in Restlet, as you are not able to add the header using `.getRequest().getHeaders().add();`

Additionally I have tried to set a challenge response however this also does not appear to work.

```
        API = new ClientResource(RequestURL);
        API.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);

        ChallengeResponse AuthHeader = new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.CUSTOM);
        AuthHeader.setRawValue("Authorization: Bearer " + APIKey);

        API.getRequest().setChallengeResponse(AuthHeader);

        API.get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have solved the issue with the following code:

```
    ChallengeResponse AuthHeader = new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_OAUTH_BEARER); 
    AuthHeader.setRawValue(APIKey);
    AuthHeader.setIdentifier("Bearer");
    API.setChallengeResponse(AuthHeader);
```